# SqlAlchemy lock foreign rows in 2 tables

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, locking

I have 2 sqlalchemy models in my DB (postgresql 9.5).

```
class AModel(Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class BModel(Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('amodel.id'), index=True)
    a = db.relationship('AModel', backref=db.backref('bmodel'))
```

Now i would like to lock record `BModel` for update (but I also want to lock related row from `AModel` table, so it won't be edited by another process).

I can lock model `BModel`:

```
db.session(BModel).query.with_for_update().filter(BModel.id == id).first()
```

But is there possibility to lock related model `AModel` in one statement? Or do I need to lock second record explicity, even if I won't update it?

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: I am using postgresql 9.5 and python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to lock rows from both tables at once, join them in your SELECT ... FOR UPDATE statement:

```
db.session.query(BModel).\
    join(Bmodel.a).\
    with_for_update().\
    filter(BModel.id == id).\
    first()
```

The documentation on the [locking clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) states that unless specific tables are named with `OF table_name [, ...]`, all tables are affected:

> If specific tables are named in a locking clause, then only rows coming from those tables are locked; any other tables used in the SELECT are simply read as usual. A locking clause without a table list affects all tables used in the statement. If a locking clause is applied to a view or sub-query, it affects all tables used in the view or sub-query. However, these clauses do not apply to WITH queries referenced by the primary query. If you want row locking to occur within a WITH query, specify a locking clause within the WITH query.

Whether or not you need to lock the row in AModel depends on what you're doing. If you'll not be using AModel's values and you're not updating AModel itself, you probably don't need a lock.

Comment: Works. Thanks for help, I actually needed to lock it to prevent updates from other threads.